# Generic example in java Explained

Tags: java, generics

I am little bit confused with this example. Names is a list of strings but we don't use generic e.x `List<String>` so it presumes a list of objects. When we call the Collections.sort without a generic type it presumes again that it is an object. If we see the sort method Comparator means that Comparator but this isn't the case with the string. String can't be super of Object?. Can someone explain how does it work?

```
   List names = Arrays.asList("peter", "anna", "mike", "xenia");

   Collections.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        return a.compareTo(b);
      }
   });


  @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
  public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    list.sort(c);
  }
```

Comment: Right off the bat, `List names = Arrays...` declares a non-generic raw type, which you should not be doing.  Use `List<String>`.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Please change `a.compare(b)` to `a.compareTo(b)`. String class does not have a `compare` method.

Comment: `Comparator<? super T>` means it can take any `unknowns` that is either of type `T` or above` So, `Comparator<String>` is fine as well as `Comparator<Object>` is fine since `Object` is a superclass of `String` but `Comparator<SubString>` will fail (even if Java allowed us to subclass a `String`).

Comment: @Buhake Sindi: passing argument new Comparator<(string)> to Comparator<( ?super T)>means that string is a supertype of T. But this is wrong since T is object type.

Comment: @Nick, not true. if `T` is of type `String`, `<? super T>` will bind to a type `T` and a superclass of `T`.

Comment: Yes if T is indeed String. In this case T is Object

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure does 3 [things](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> 1. Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded.
> 2. Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> 3. Generate [bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.

Your question is about number 3.

```
new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        return a.compareTo(b);
      }
   }
```

Creates an anonymous inner class that has a bridge method `public int compare(Object a, Object b)` which casts the parameters to `String` and calls the other method.

The following is `javap` output in which you can see the generated bridge method:

```
class Check$1 implements java.util.Comparator<java.lang.String> {
  Check$1();
  public int compare(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  public int compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: checkcast     #31   // class java/lang/String
       5: aload_2
       6: checkcast     #31   // class java/lang/String
       9: invokevirtual #40   // Method compare:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
      12: ireturn

}
```

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain what is the problem with this answer?